# Multi-objective optimization with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization

I would like to know if anyone can help me  with a multi-optimization problem using MATLAB.
I have data from a spectroscopy test whose output is *I* [intensity] and *s* [momentum  transfer].
I need to find a function [*G*] that satisfies the following two constraints:

[Equation 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ILz0.gif)
[Equation 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s17Hw.gif)

Where *a*,*b* and *c* are constants.
Note:b is assumed to constant, however, it can also take the form of a polynomial of even powers e.g., *a0 + a1.s^2 + a2.s^4 + a3.s^6*

Equation 1 is to be applied to a selected interval at the end of the data to fulfill the limit requirement.

With MATLAB I'm able to solve the integral with the function fsolve.

```
fun=@(x) Equation 2
```

`[x,fval]=fsolve (Equation 2,x0)`

With *a*,*b*,and *c* equal to *x(1)*, *x(2)*, *x(3)* and *x0* the initial guess for the parameters.

This will in fact calculate the constants a,b and c to solve the integral, however, I also need that the limit constraint be satisfied

Does any one know how I can implement this limit? 
I'm wondering if I can do this with this kind of expression.

```
q_range=q(range1:range2)
I_range=I(range1:range2)


fun=@(x)sum (Equation 1.^2) 


[x2,fval]=fminsearch sum(Equation 1.^2)
```

Since both equations have different length does anyone know to implement both constraints using something like **fgoalattain** and pass as function and goal the previous expressions?  Any recommendation for a different approach?

Best Regards!

Comment: Cross-posted [on Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2183190/multiobjective-optimization-with-matlab). Please don't cross-post.

Comment: you should use optimization algorithms like GA, ant colony , swarm optimization , etc. it is not simple straight forward problem which could be simply done,